# "Clipping" text from a output pipe in Node.JS

Tags: database, node.js, grep, ping

I am writing my first application in node.js, i am not very much familiar with windows as i am linux, and i am wondering how i can take a output of a child proccess like ping and just get the milliseconds off the end of the ping, for example, this is an output of pinging google.com.

```
    Pinging google.com [74.125.226.4] with 32 bytes of
    Reply from 74.125.226.4: bytes=32 time=90ms TTL=53
    Reply from 74.125.226.4: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=5
    Reply from 74.125.226.4: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=53
```

I would like to be able to clip the time ^^ off of the string and put it for use in something else like storing it in a database. This procedure is called "Grep" in linux, is there anything i can do in node that would work cross platform as there isnt a grep equivalent in windows that i know of.

```
    var sys = require('sys')
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
    exec("ping -n 3 google.com", puts);
```

This is my node.js code so far, this just pings google in a child proccess, and i get the response in the puts variable, i would like to be able to just log the time in the database.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract what you like, and split lines by using the (os-dependent EOL property of the *os* module from node.js. Here is a complete example (I modified the ping command to be working on OS X). You can use the *args* property to provide further arguments to the regular expression constructor, most important "g" which will find all occurences on a single line, instead of the first one.

```
var sys  = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var EOL  = require('os').EOL;

function funGrep(cmd,callback,search,args){
    exec(cmd,function(err,stdout){
        if(!err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if(!stdout)
            return;
        var lines = stdout.toString().split(EOL);
        var re = new RegExp(search,args);
        for(var line in lines){
            var results = lines[line].match(re);
            if(results){
                for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                    callback(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

funGrep("ping -c 3 google.com",console.log,"time=[0-9\.]+ ms");
/*
output on OS X:
time=27.878 ms
time=27.652 ms
time=28.134 ms
*/
//for Windows:
funGrep("ping -t 3 google.com",console.log,"time=[0-9\.]+ ?ms");
```

Comment: When i run this with the modified ping for windows, i get nothing from the console.log, is there any reason why? Thank you for the extremely amazing grep meathod, i just wish i could get a console.log, its specifically in the callback console.log but i just get nothing

Comment: @user3521578 I modified my code to include a Windows version (and error handling). The problem was (beside the parameter) that there is no space before the *ms* suffix on Windows